# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key 'webview'. Trying to create a spotify sign in button

Tags: xcode, storyboard, spotify

```
import WebKit
import UIKit


class DissTrackSignUp: UIViewController {
    
    var webView: WKWebView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds)
            view.addSubview(webView)
        }

    @IBAction func signInSpotifyTapped(_ sender: Any) {
            let authURL = URL(string: "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=c36fff5175844337a4da991b6eb0436f&response_type=code&redirect_uri=myapp-spotify://&scope=user-read-email")!
            let request = URLRequest(url: authURL)
            webView.load(request)
            webView.isHidden = false
        }
    }
```

I am trying to get the user to log in with spotify by redirection in Xcode, but the app will crash before the app is loaded and the launch screen hasnt disappeared.

Ive tried every possible thing like restarting xcode, reconnectiing and deleting outlets, and rewriting code.

Comment: There are no outlets in the code you posted.

Comment: `webview` and `webView` are not the same thing.

Comment: Press ⇧⌘F and search for `webview` (all lowercase). Maybe there is an unused element or connection in Interface Builder.

Comment: @vadian done that, and changed the webview and webView problem, still nothing. Here is updated code.  import WebKit
import UIKit


class DissTrackSignUp: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
    
    
    IBOutlet var WebView: WKWebView!
    
    
    IBAction func signInSpotifyTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!
        
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        WebView.load(request)
        
        
        }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
} I put google just as an example site

Comment: This is the third different spelling of *(w|W)eb(v|V)iew*. Case sensitivity matters.

Comment: @vadian Yes, i’ve deleted all outlets and reconnected them to all be WebView.